# How to sort the selected items of multiselect?

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, kendo-ui, multi-select, kendo-multiselect

I ordered the source, but I can not do it for 'value'(view of selected items).

I use the multiselect with MVVM.

My html code:

```
<select id="doc" data-role="multiselect"
data-value-primitive="true"
data-text-field="name"
data-value-field="id"
data-bind="value: valueDoc,
source: sourceDoc"></select>
```

My js code:

```
vm = kendo.observable({

sourceDoc: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            data: [],
            sort: { field: "name", dir: "asc" }
        })
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you mean with *I can not do it for 'value'* ?

Comment: The datasource is sortable.

Comment: the selected items are not displayed in alphabetical order

Comment: Can you create a http://dojo.telerik.com/ with your issue?

Comment: The photo perfectly describes the problem.
I can not create a jsfiddle because it is a part of a long code, with external libraries and scripts that do not allow me to divide the code into a small part.

Comment: The correct order should be this: Africa,Asia and Europe.

Comment: I know that, I just like to see a working demo of your code to perform some tests. I have no time to create a new one from scratch.

Comment: http://dojo.telerik.com/IdutA